# How to improve sharpness in image using GPUImage

Tags: ios, camera, gpuimage

I'm using [Brad Larson's GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage) and [DLCImagePicker](https://github.com/gobackspaces/DLCImagePickerController) right now and they both work great.

However, images taken using the controller and GPUImage are noticably worse than images taken from Instagram, Path, or even the Camera app, for example.

Here's Instagram (the pic looks slightly sharper)
[image: sharper]

And here's a shot using DLC+GPUImage
[image: Blurry]

Comment: It looks like there's some downsampling occurring in the latter image. Is this on the iPhone 4? I ask, because on that one device, the GPU can't handle the size of still photos produced, so I have to downsample them. Beyond that, what's being displayed here, the finished photo or the preview video from the camera?

Comment: @BradLarson These shots were taken from the iPhone 5.  The finished photo is being displayed here.  The preview video quality from the camera using GPUImage is substantially the same to the preview video quality from Instagram, Path, etc. Are there any settings I can play with to fix the quality of the finished photo?

Comment: Does the final photo itself look any less clear? If those images are the photo being displayed above, it's going to have to be downsampled to be shown in an area that small. Instagram and Path might be using better downsampling than linear interpolation for their photo display. You could try using a GPUImageLanczosResamplingFilter with -forceProcessingAtSize: set to the size of your view in the filter chain right before the view to use a much sharper downsampling algorithm. It will generate a significantly better thumbnail from a larger image.

Comment: Thanks for your help Brad. The final photo does look less clear than the preview video.  

I did the following: 
`filter = [[GPUImageLanczosResamplingFilter alloc] init];
[filter forceProcessingAtSize:CGSizeMake(640, 640)];`

and the output is actually blurrier than without this filter.